# Best way to do convex optimization in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

I'm looking to do some simple convex optimization in Haskell; nothing too fancy, just minimizing linear functions with some quadratic constraints. I've come across [HVX](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/14sp-cs240h/projects/copeland_haggblade.pdf) and am just wondering if that is the best package for this purpose or if there is a standard alternative. Thanks!

Comment: HVX appears to be an unmaintained student project never uploaded to Hackage. Feel free to use it, but don't expect any kind of support.

Answer (score 0):

The `ad` package has several helpful routines and a gradient descent operation or two.  For example:

```
$ cabal install --pacakge-env . --lib ad
$ ghci
> import Numeric.AD
> take 1 $ drop 10000 $ gradientDescent (\[x] -> (x-1)^2 + 3) [10]
[[1.0000000000377052]]
> conjugateGradientDescent  (\[x] -> (x-1)^2 + 3) [10]
[[10.0],[1.0]]
```

We see the function we are minimizing, the inputs as a traversable (list in this case), and an initial starting point `[10]`.  This is the package that underlies the `optimization` package and should provide a nice start even if it doesn't solve your problem outright.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try.